# How to fix Activesupport compatible versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, activesupport

I recently installed the gem "Paperclip" by using:

gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

```
rails (= 4.1.5) was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
  activesupport (= 4.1.5)

rails (= 4.1.5) was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
  activesupport (= 4.1.5)

rails (= 4.1.5) was resolved to 4.1.5, which depends on
  activesupport (= 4.1.5)
```

I believe there is some kind of dependecy/conflict issue with my Paperclip/Activesupport/Rails versions and can't put my finger on it.

Tried sudo install Activesupport (played around with different versions) - no luck. Bundle update, bundle install, played around with gemfile.lock etc. I'm stuck in a loop.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by downgrading the Ruby version, then re-running bundle update, bundle install.